# Running Glassfish JAX-RS server on GAE not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, glassfish, jax-rs

Long story short, I had written a GlassFish server within my Intellij IDEA, however, I noticed that I would need a server to deploy it on, so I did some research and found that Google App Engine (Google Cloud Platform) would be the way to go.

I used Google Cloud Tools Plugin for Intellij to add support for the App Engine (Standard). Everything went smooth, I selected the war file to deploy and the Google Cloud Project to deploy it on, however, when I sent a `GET` request to an URL (e.g. `localhost:8080/cases/all`) I get an error 404 status message. Normally this would return a JSON array filled with JSON Objects.

I got an Application class like follows:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class Server extends Application{

    /**
     * Returns all the classes in the server.
     * @return Set of all classes used in server.
     */
    @Override
    public final Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet h = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        // Add classes to h
        return h;
    }
}
```

My web.xml and my appengine-web.xml, both located in `./web/WEB-INF`, look respectively like:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

And

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Running the Glassfish server locally works without any problems. As soon as I try to deploy GAE Standard (Local) Server, it doesn't work. I can't access paths anymore, every path returns a 404 and this message in the Intellij console (when trying to access (/cases/all):

```
jul 04, 2018 3:38:24 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /cases/all
```

The type of the artifact I'm deploying is `Web Application: Exploded`.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are developing on GlassFish which provides the full Java EE API (including JAX-RS) but deploying to GAE which (according to the log message) uses Eclipse Jetty under the covers. Jetty does not provide all Java EE APIs, so there is nothing to process your JAX-RS annotations and provide the paths you specify.

If you really need to deploy to GAE, I would recommend you find an implementation of JAX-RS which can be bundled with your application (Jersey should do, which is the same implementation that GlassFish uses). You should also test it out locally by deploying to Jetty instead of GlassFish.

If you would rather use GlassFish, then you might do better with AWS' Elastic Beanstalk which [should support GlassFish 4.0](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/11/05/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-python3-4-java7-glassfish4-0-and-java8-glassfish4-1/).

A third option would be to use GAE's [custom runtime option](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart), which lets you use your own Dockerfile. Payara Micro (a lightweight app server derived from the GlassFish Web edition) will be able to run your application and there is [a public Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/payara/micro/) for it, meaning you can create your own Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM payara/micro
COPY myApp.war $DEPLOY_DIR
```

Payara Micro will detect your WAR file and deploy it automatically. By default, the path to your app will include the name of the WAR file (e.g. http://localhost:8080/myApp/cases/all) so if you want it to deploy without the file name in the path, rename the file to `ROOT.war`.

Hope that helps.